# How to efficiently make the function pointer in the java class?

Tags: java

While coding in Java programming, I have a question as below.

Below is c++ code. As you know, variable `Alpha` in the `SomParam class` is function pointer. When the user set the function address to the `Alpha` in the constructor, then the variable `Alpha` executes the current functions.

```
double lin_alpha(double alpha_0, int t, Subscript rlen, double) {
  return alpha_0 * (1.0 - (double) t / rlen);
}

double inv_alpha(double alpha_0, int t, Subscript rlen, double C) {
  //double C = rlen / INV_ALPHA_CONST;

  return alpha_0 * C / (C + t);
}

#define LIN_ALPHA 1
#define INV_ALPHA 2

class SomParam{
public:
  typedef double Alpha(double, int, int, double);
protected:
  Alpha *_alpha;
  int _xdim;
  int _ydim;

public: 
  SomParam(int AlphaType,int xdim, int ydim) {
        if (AlphaType == LIN_ALPHA) _alpha = lin_alpha;
        else _alpha = lin_alpha;
    _xdim = xdim;
    _ydim = ydim;
  }
```

My question is that I want to know how to convert the above codes into Java version. Since Java has no pointer concept, I had a hard time converting it into Java version. I've known that interface might be able to replace the function pointer in Java but I couldn't apply it to my code.
How to convert the above one into java version?

Ps. I hope that you should not using the lambda expression since I am using the Java 7.

Comment: I don't think there is function pointer in java. However java8 lambda parameter looks like one pass a function as a parameter.

Comment: Why don't you use Java 8?  Java 7 has been obsolete for quite some time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is with Java 8 lambda expressions.  But since you want to avoid those, here is a rough translation of your C++ code into Java 7.

I've used a static inner interface to represent the type of the function pointers, and instances of anonymous implementations of this interface to represent the functions themselves.  In my opinion, this is better than using an `enum`, because it doesn't imply any relationship between the various functions, other than that they have the same signature.

I've set this all up with constants, and shown how to select which of the constant values is appropriate to store in the object that you're instantiating.  I've taken a few liberties with data types and so on.

```
public class AlphaAdjuster {

    private static interface AlphaCalculator {
        double calculate(double alpha0, int t, int rlen, double c);
    }

    public static final int LIN_ALPHA = 1;
    public static final int INV_ALPHA = 2;
    private static final AlphaCalculator LIN_ALPHA_CALCULATOR = new AlphaCalculator(){
        @Override
        public double calculate(double alpha0, int t, int rlen, double c) {
            return alpha0 * (1.0 - (double) t / rlen);
        }};
    private static final AlphaCalculator INV_ALPHA_CALCULATOR = new AlphaCalculator(){
        @Override
        public double calculate(double alpha0, int t, int rlen, double c) {
            return alpha0 * c / (c + t);
        }};

    private AlphaCalculator calculator;
    private int xDim;
    private int yDim;

    public AlphaAdjuster(int alphaType, int xDim, int yDim) {
        if (alphaType == LIN_ALPHA) {
            calculator = LIN_ALPHA_CALCULATOR;
        } else {
            calculator = INV_ALPHA_CALCULATOR;
        }
        this.xDim = xDim;
        this.yDim = yDim;
    }

    public double calculate(double alpha0, int t, int rlen, double c) {
        return calculator.calculate(alpha0, t, rlen, c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest creating a strategy pattern enum implementing the two functions and passing that directly into your constructor:

```
public enum AlphaType {
    LIN_ALPHA {
        @Override
        public double compute(double alpha_0, int t, Subscript rlen, double C) {
            // FIXME t / rlen isn't valid in Java
            return alpha_0 * (1.0 - (double) t / rlen);
        }
    },

    INV_ALPHA {
        @Override
        public double compute(double alpha_0, int t, Subscript rlen, double C) {
            //double C = rlen / INV_ALPHA_CONST;
            return alpha_0 * C / (C + t);
        }
    };

    public abstract double compute(double alpha_0, int t, Subscript rlen, double C);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not very familiar with C++, but I think I understand what you want.

You're correct that an interface seems to be what you want. You can read about interfaces [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), but they will accomplish what you want.

For example, say you have the interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public int sort(int a, int b);
}
```

This allows the user of `MyInterface` to define their own `sort()` method, depending on what they want.

```
MyInterface foo = new MyInterface(){
    @Override
    public int sort(int a, int b){
        return (a >= b)? a : b;
    }
}
```

This instantiates a `MyInterface` that gives the sorts by the max number. Calling `foo.sort(1,4)` will return `4`.

In your case, you would have an interface with a method that looks like `public double alpha(double a, int b, int b, double c)` or the like. Then, the user would instantiate your interface and override the `alpha()` method to do what they want.

Comment: I've *never* thought of an interface as a function pointer.  My advice would be to stick to a solid answer and don't rely on correlations between C++ and Java.

Comment: @Makoto Agreed, I don't think one should make these kinds of connections, but I was just trying to explain interfaces in c++ terms, so he could understand it. I'll edit to make it clear that interfaces are different from function pointers, but in this instance can be used to accomplish what he wants.

Comment: This answer has the guts of a good solution.  Unfortunately, the terminology in the last sentence is very strange.  We don't instantiate an interface then override its methods.  We instantiate an anonymous implementation of the interface.